# Unable to start more than one server thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to create a program in python where I have to run two classes at the same time. So what I'm trying to do is that I just create a thread for every instance of the class. Programming is pretty new for me, so this is what we call a "user error" ;)

Here is my code:

```
import threading
import sys

servers = [
    ["Server 01", "192.168.0.1", 12345, "password"],
    ["Server 02", "192.168.0.1", 12346, "password"],
]

def main():
    for row in servers:
        serverName = row[0]
        serverAddress = row[1]
        rconPort = row[2]
        rconPass = row[3]
        th = threading.Thread(target = rcon.RconProtocol(serverAddress, rconPort, rconPass, serverName))
        th.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code works great for the first server in `servers`. But then it stops after `th.start()`. So it doesn't matter what ever I do after `th.start()`, it doesn't run. `RconProtocol` doesn't do anything special except listening to a socket. And here is where I think the problem is. I have an infinite loop in the `RconProtocol` class (`while True`).

I tried to do a similar function (I did another called `two` too):

```
def one():
    while True:
        print "one"
```

and just specified it as a target for my thread, and I got the same issue. It works without the while-loop (just print "one").

So I'm a little bit curious why this is happening and what I do wrong. I usually see myself as a good google person, but I couldn't find any similar cases. My head doesn't like examples where you have to use time, or random examples. I think I have to see more practical examples.

By the way, is it "wrong" to place a while-loop in a class like this? Should it be outside in some kind of way? Should I maybe create threads in my `RconProtocol` class instead?

Hope this is enough information.

Thanks in advance!

/Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling rcon.RconProtocol in main thrad. Replcae following line

```
th = threading.Thread(target=rcon.RconProtocol(serverAddress, rconPort, rconPass, serverName))
```

with

```
th = threading.Thread(target=rcon.RconProtocol, args=(serverAddress, rconPort, rconPass, serverName))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it is a bad idea to use a while loop as the high level control in a thread. Python threads are good for blocking situations where you spend most of your time waiting for something and then react. In your case you should use a `threading.Queue` to send commands to your thread to be forwarded to your server. This way your thread will be blocked waiting on the Queue or transmitting a message to your server.